# Rails and RSpec database transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am struggling to mock out the database tests for the following code, which uses two different databases:

```
     ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        Storage.get_db_table.transaction do
          do_stuff()
        end
      end
```

In My RSpec tests I have the following:

```
   before :each do
      allow(Storage).to receive(:get_db_table)
      allow(MyOtherTable).to receive(:transaction)
    end
```

`get_db_table` looks like:

```
def get_db_table 
 MyOtherTable
end
```

The class `MyOtherTable` looks like this:

```
class MyOtherTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  con_name = get_conn_name
  establish_connection configurations[con_name]
  self.table_name = 'table_name_here'
end
```

But I get the following error:

`Double received unexpected message :get_db_table with (no args)`

How can I properly mock this out?

Comment: Can you include enough of your code to actually give us a clue as to what the object under test is and what your spec is? This is way too abstract.

Comment: Apologies I managed to find a solution in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
Storage.stub_chain(: get_db_table, :transaction).and_yield()
```

In case it helps others